# SQL ABS() is returning unexpected decimal when applied on divisible data

Tags: sql

On applying abs on divisible data, whole number quotient is converted to decimal.

```
create table #data ( ConditionValue money, ConditionRateNbr real)
              insert into #data values(9665.77,37.61)
              select abs(conditionvalue/conditionrateNbr) Using_Abs ,* 
         from #data

--Using_Abs         ConditionValue  ConditionRateNbr
--256.999969482422  9665.77         37.61
```

Why this happens and how to solve?

Comment: Whats is your database?

Comment: Does `ConditionRateNbr` need to be a `real`? I suspect you probably use a `decimal` and then your division would come out to the integral value you expected.

Comment: Rounding and representation issue when using a binary floating-point type. It'll be worse when using a 4-byte type such as REAL, but DOUBLE will do the same thing. This calculation works OK in MySQL 5.5, 5.6, and SQLite at SQLFIddle.com, but returns funky results in PostgreSQL and SQL Server. (Oracle's not working right now, but based on my experience with Oracle I'll say it'll work as expected). Don't EVER use binary floating-point values (REAL and DOUBLE data types) for monetary quantities. Use DECIMAL, NUMBER (on Oracle), or MONEY where available. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I have seen using money is more reliable than decimal.
Here is another example.

Why on earth decimal considers 3/1.5 as 1.5, I do not know !!!

```
declare @real real = 1.5, @realup money=3
select @realUp numerator, @real denominator, @realup /cast (@real as money) money, @realup /cast(@real as decimal) decimal

--numerator denominator money   decimal
--3.00      1.5         2.00    1.50000000000000000000000
```

Comment: You didn't specify a scale for your decimal value so it basically  got treated as integer. That means it was rounded up to 2 before the division and 3.0/2 is 1.5.

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with the "real" data type being an "approximate-number", see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx. My knowledge of SQL is not deep enough to give a detailed explanation but I do have a solution, use the decimal data type i/o real:

```
create table #data ( ConditionValue money, ConditionRateNbr decimal(38,20))
              insert into #data values(9665.77,37.61)
              select abs(conditionvalue/conditionrateNbr) Using_Abs ,* 
         from #data
```

IMO it's usually smarter to use decimal than real to avoid this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming sql server, but if you run the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE #data
(
    ConditionValue MONEY
,   ConditionRateNbr REAL
)
INSERT  INTO #data
VALUES  ( 9665.77, 37.61 )

SELECT  *
INTO data
FROM    (
SELECT  ABS(ConditionValue / ConditionRateNbr) Using_Abs
,       conditionValue / ConditionRateNbr test
,       *
FROM    #data
)a

SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS AS C WHERE C.TABLE_NAME = 'data'

DROP TABLE #data
DROP TABLE data
```

You'll see that the result of the division is a `real`. [The ISO synonym for real is float(24).](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) The `ABS(numeric_expression)` function [Returns the same type as numeric_expression.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189800.aspx) Apparently, the `ABS` function returns a default `float`, [which is `float(53)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx). `float(53)` contains 15 digits, so you get 15 digits returned.

So the returned datatype is not, as you might at first think, a `decimal`, but instead another `float`, defaulted to its max size (so to speak).

If you define your fields as `decimals`, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx) what you are likely to get.